# Vimperator: what's the comand to copy the target of a specific link on a page?

Tags: firefox, vimperator

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`;y`

You need to press `;` to enter "[extended hints mode](http://vimperator.org/help/vimperator/hints.xhtml#extended-hints)", and then `y` to "yank" (i.e., copy) the link's `href` value.